# Create a loop that changes the number on a vector's name - Matlab

Tags: matlab, vector

I am trying to create a while-loop on MatLab that will alter the numerical bit of a vector's name. 
To be precise, I have created an initial column vector named p1=[0.7;0.3]; also, I have generated a matrix named A = [0.8 0.1;0.2 0.9].
What I want to achieve is create a while-loop with n from 1 to 7 where at each state I will multiply the matrix A with vector p(n). 
For example:

```
A = [ 0.8 0.1; 0.2 0.9 ];
p1 = [0.7; 0.3];
n=1;
while n<=7
    q=A*p(n);
    n=n+1;
    p(n)=q;
end
```

At the end I would like to be able to see vector p7.

Any suggestions?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Allocated `p` as a `2xn` matrix and assign the multiplication to each column.

Comment: Please, take the advice in all the answer to use the number as a key in a matrix as it is easy to implement. To change variable names in the loop using some magic tricks is just against the whole idea of programming and scripting and is a very bad habit.

Answer (score 3):

What your trying to do is multiply from the left of `p` by `A` 6 times, so if the last result is what you want, you can write:

```
A = [ 0.8 0.1; 0.2 0.9 ];
p1 = [0.7; 0.3];
p7 = A^6*p
```

output:

```
p7 =
      0.37647
      0.62353
```

If you want all the multiplications by `A`, you can write:

```
p = bsxfun(@(n,p) A^n*p,0:6,repmat(p1,1,7))
```

which will output:

```
p =
      0.7         0.59        0.513       0.4591      0.42137      0.39496      0.37647
      0.3         0.41        0.487       0.5409      0.57863      0.60504      0.62353
```

You want 7 different variables instead of one, so first, that's not how you work with MATLAB, and I'm quite sure you can just write `p(5,:)` instead of `p5` to get the fifth variable. However, if it *is* so important, the right way to do it is with structs:

```
for k = 1:7
    ps.(['p' num2str(k)]) = p(:,k);
end
```

This will create a struct named `ps` with fields `p1` to `p7`:

```
ps = 

    p1: [2x1 double]
    p2: [2x1 double]
    p3: [2x1 double]
    p4: [2x1 double]
    p5: [2x1 double]
    p6: [2x1 double]
    p7: [2x1 double]
```

and each field can be referenced by `ps.p1`, `ps.p2` etc... for example:

```
>> ps.p5

ans =

      0.42137
      0.57863
```

Comment: Thanks EBH, pretty close but I guess I haven't described efficiently what exactly I want to accomplish. I do not wish to have a single 2x7 matrix but multiple p1,p2,p3,p4...p7 column vectors. My aim is to be able to change the number on vector's name (from p1 to p7) each time the procedure performs a loop. Hope I explained that better now. I am not interested on the result as how to be able to change the number at the end of the vector's name, I am not sure if I can even do that though.

Comment: If A matrix has considerable entries with moderate size n, then the numbers blow up pretty quickly.

Comment: @Sitherion you shouldn't make so many variables, just work with a simple matrix. If you _do_ want to, better do it with structs. See my edit to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, this is what you're trying to do:

```
A = [ 0.8 0.1; 0.2 0.9 ];
p(:,1) = [0.7; 0.3];
p(:,7)= 0; % Pre-allocation

n=1;
while n<7
    q=A*p(:,n);
    n=n+1;
    p(:,n)=q;
end
```

**Output:-**

```
>> p(:,7)

ans =
    0.3765
    0.6235
```

**Edit:-**
Now as you've mentioned that you need separate `p2,p3,...p7` which is ***not recommended*** but if you still want to do it, it can be done as follows:-

```
A = [ 0.8 0.1; 0.2 0.9 ];
p1 = [0.7; 0.3];

n=1;
while n<7
    eval(['q', ' = ', 'p', num2str(n),';']);
    assignin('base', ['p' num2str(n+1)], A*q)
    n=n+1;
end
```

**Output:-**

```
>> p7

p7 =
    0.3765
    0.6235
```

Comment: Hi Sardar, thanks for your answer. As I explained to EBH bellow I am trying to create a new vector every time my procedure performs a loop. So at the end of the loop and when n=7 to have created p2 p3 p4 p5 p6 p7 vectors, with p7 as correctly showed to contain the values 0.3765 and 0.6235.

Comment: @Sitherion That's something matlab strongly recommends not to do so. They recommend using structs.

Comment: You should try to avoid [eval](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eval.html) at all cost (see [Evading eval](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/28/evading-eval/) for details) but I guess you are just showing a different way of doing it compared to the other answers.

Comment: I am not blaming you. I am just saying it is ridiculous (which is mainly caused by the question itself). I think you firmly agree that this is the wrong route for the OP. I think it is good to emphasize that in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use a proper allocated matrix

```
n = 7
p = [p1 zeros(2,n-1)];
for x = 2:n
  p(:,x) = A*p(:,x-1);
end
```